# Jenkins pipeline error in handling json file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm newbie to Jenkins pipeline and writing a groovy script to parse a json file. However I'm facing an error which many have faced but none of the solutions worked for me. Below is my Jenkinsfile and error msg.

```
def envname = readJSON file: '${env.WORKSPACE}/manifest.json'
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo WORKSPACE
                sh "ls -a ${WORKSPACE}"
            } 
        }
        }
 }
```

> [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
> [Pipeline] readJSON
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException:
> Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing Perhaps you forgot
> to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node    at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:30)

I even tried `readJSON file: '${WORKSPACE}/manifest.json` but that didn't work too. I'm sure the mistake is with the first line since when removing that line, there execution is successful. The docs are pretty helpful but I'm not able to track down where exactly I'm going wrong that is why posted here.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following methods `def envname = readJSON file: "./manifest.json"` and `def envname = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/manifest.json"` and even tried them defining under the `steps` block. Nothing worked. Below is the error msg I recieved when I defined them under step block

> WorkflowScript: 5: Expected a step @ line 7, column 13
> def envname =
> ^

Below is the official syntax doc of readJson and I can see that I'm using the correct syntax only. but still doesn't work as expected.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this myself with the help of "Matt Schuchard"'s below answer. I'm not sure whether this is the only way to solve but this worked for me.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { 
        stage('Json-Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def envname = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/manifest.json"
                    element1 = "${envname.dev}"
                    echo element1
                }
            } 
        }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`'${env.WORKSPACE}/manifest.json'` is interpolating the Groovy `env` map as a shell variable. You need to interpolate it as a Groovy variable like `"${env.WORKSPACE}/manifest.json"`.

`sh "ls -a ${WORKSPACE}"` is interpolating the shell environment variable `WORKSPACE` as a Groovy variable. You need to interpolate it as a shell variable like `sh 'ls -a ${WORKSPACE}'`.

`echo WORKSPACE` is attempting to resolve the shell variable `WORKSPACE` as a first class Groovy variable expression. You need to use the Groovy `env` map instead like `echo env.WORKSPACE`.

As for the global variable indefinite type assignment on the first line: if it still throws the error above after making those fixes, then it may be due to invalid use of scripted syntax in a declarative syntax pipeline. You likely need to place it inside a `step` block within your pipeline in that case.

Comment: tried your suggestions but still didn't work. This time it was a different error. It couldn't recognize the `def` when inserted within a `steps` block. Don't think using a `script{}` inside `steps` would be suitable here, right? Will it be?

Comment: @vishal If declarative syntax, then you may need to nest inside `script` block if it is considered scripted.

Comment: bringing it under `script` worked for me. I've added the final script itself as an answer.